# Accessing a constant via visualforce page without using a controller

Tags: visualforce

I need to access a constant that holds a URL via an email template(= visual-force page) without using a controller. Because if I use a controller I will need to write test code and also maintain more code.

I have just seen that there are some out-of-the-box features that can be used directly in visual-force pages. For instance, $Api.Partner_Server_URL__xxx, that will return an API endpoint.

I would like to achieve the same, I mean to retrieve a custom URL in the same manner. Something like $Company.Url = www.company.com.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mechanism you could use is a [hierarchical custom setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm). Values can be accessed directly in Visualforce using [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm).

Here is the example from the docs:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:inputField value="{!usr.Workstation_Height__c}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="helpWorkstationHeight" 
        rendered="{!$Setup.App_Prefs__c.Show_Help_Content__c}">
        Enter the height for your workstation in inches, measured from the 
        floor to top of the work surface.
    </apex:outputPanel>
    ...
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution; however, only profiles that have activated the security feature "Customize Application" can access the custom settings. Activating this feature will lead to a security threat. I which Salesforce would provide a better solution for this cases.